# laravel Database Faker relationship

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, faker

Im trying to create fake data base for testing for my two tables Endpoint and Request , here is my Endpoint factory

```
class EndpointFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Endpoint::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'url' => $this->faker->unique()->url,
        ];
    }
}
```

** this is my request table factory **

```
class RequestFactory extends Factory
{
    /** @var string  */
    protected $model = Request::class;

    public function definition() : array
    {
        return [
            'status'      => $this->faker->randomElement([200, 201, 401, 403, 422]),
            'endpoint_id' => 1,
            'user_id'     => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 100),
            'method'      => $this->faker->randomElement(['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']),
            'duration'    => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10),
            'result'      => json_encode(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name']),
        ];
    }
}
```

** here my models for the two tables **

```
class Request extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'requests';

    protected static function newFactory(): RequestFactory
    {
        return RequestFactory::new();
    }

    public function endpoint(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Endpoint::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Endpoint extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var string[] 
     */
    protected $fillable = ['url'];

    /**
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $table = 'endpoints';

    protected static function newFactory(): EndpointFactory
    {
        return EndpointFactory::new();
    }

    public function requests(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Request::class);
    }
}
```

** the problem with testing  , i want the relationship too for exemple **

```
 public function test_api_structure_for_single_Endpoint()
    {
   
      $Endpoint = Endpoint::factory()
      ->has(Request::factory()->count(5))->create();
}
```

** but i get only Endpoint table , the request table wont be created like in the laravel docs **

**ps im using laravel 9 **

Answer (score 0):

Factories just create database table entries, not actual tables. If your entire table is missing you need to create a migration.

if it's just the entries that aren't being added, you can use the `->each()` chain function to iterate over each created endpoint, and save requests against them:

```
$Endpoint = Endpoint::factory()->create()->each( function($e) {
  $e->saveMany(Request::factory()->count(5)->make());
});
```

Comment: i already have Migration , but(  factory(App\Request::class ) is not any more supported in laravel 8* and above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make dummy data to model and its relations, remove the foreign column. Your Test file remains the same

```php
return [
    'status'      => $this->faker->randomElement([200, 201, 401, 403, 422]),
    // 'endpoint_id' => 1,
   'user_id'     => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 100),
   'method'      => $this->faker->randomElement(['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']),
   'duration'    => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10),
   'result'      => json_encode(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name']),
];
```